# How is Small talk's message to:do: implemented behind the scenes?

Tags: smalltalk

```
result := String new. 
1 to: 10 do: [:n | result := result, n printString, ’ ’].
```

> Everything in smalltalk is an object and the objects interact through
>   messages.

I couldn't understand how the above code is understanding the message to:do:

How is it able to iterate the block from 1 to 10?
How does it know it has to repeat the block that many number of times?

Can someone explain what happens under the hood?

Answer (score 8):

All Smalltalk messages follow the pattern `<receiver> <message>.`. In this case the receiver is `1` (a subinstance of `Number`), and the message is `to:do:`.

You can browse class `Number` and see the implementation of `to:do:` right there:

`to: stop do: aBlock 
    | nextValue |
    nextValue := self.
    [nextValue <= stop]
        whileTrue: 
            [aBlock value: nextValue.
            nextValue := nextValue + 1]`

In your example, `stop` is `10` and `aBlock` is `[:n | result := result, n printString, ’ ’]`. So indeed, it is sending `value:` to `aBlock` repeatedly.

Now, in addition to that, many Smalltalks generate special byte code when they see the `for:to:` message, but this is just an optimization.

Comment: BTW, this is at least somewhat related to the Church Encoding of Numerals in λ-calculus, although not as closely as Smalltalk's encoding of Booleans, which effectively *is* the Church Encoding of Booleans in λ-calculus. In the Church Encoding of Numerals, numbers are encoded *as* iteration (so, a number and a loop with that number of iterations are the same thing), whereas in Smalltalk iteration is encoded as a method of numbers.

Comment: Also, in a Smalltalk with Proper Tail Calls, it could be implemented with tail-recursion, which may or may not be more elegant in your eyes. (It is in mine.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the method

```
m
  1 to: 10 do: [:i | self doSomethingWith: i]
```

Here are the bytecodes that Pharo generates

```
    pushConstant: 1                   ; i := 1
    popIntoTemp: 0                    ;
@2: pushTemp: 0                       ; i <= 10 ?
    pushConstant: 10                  ;
    send #'<='                        ;
    jumpFalse: @1                     ; if false, go to end
    self                              ; self doSomethingWith: i
    pushTemp: 0                       ;
    send #doSomethingWith:            ;
    pop                               ; 
    pushTemp: 0                       ; i := i + 1
    pushConstant: 1                   ;
    send #'+'                         ;
    popIntoTemp: 0                    ;
    jumpTo: @2                        ; loop
@1: returnSelf
```

As you can see the message `#to:do` is never sent, while `#'<='` and `#+` are (even though they are not in the source code!). Why? Because of what Bert said in his answer: these messages are optimized by the Smalltalk compiler. In the case of Pharo the optimization happens in `#to:do:`. In other dialects `#to:do:` is implemented in terms of `#whileTrue:`, which is the one that gets optimized.

Once you have understood how this works *under the hood*, get back to think of it as if `#to:do:` were a regular message with receiver `1` and arguments `10` and the block `[:i | self doSomethingWith: i]`. The optimization shouldn't obscure the semantics that your mind needs to follow.